# jQuery Ajax Data does not correspond to supplied data through web service when using Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, web-services, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery's Autocomplete with a web service. Standard stuff.

The problem is that when I attempt to get the selected 'value' as below, I am shown the 'label' data.

Here's the code segment that binds the returned data:

```
// suggest/addresses/{howMany:int?}/{useBoundary?}/{boundarySize?}/{useBias?}/{query?}/{latitude?}/{longitude?}
        var url = "/api/v1/Suggest/Addresses/UK/20/0/0/1/"
        $('#pickupaddress').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: { query: request.term, 
                        latitude: $('#Latitude').val(), 
                        longitude: $('#Longitude').val()
                        },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.DisplayAddress, // holds full address = correct
                                value: item.LocatorId // also holds full address but should be database ID
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#pickupaddress').val(ui.item.label);
                $('#LocatorID').val(ui.item.value);
                // But below still shows label as the selected value
                alert('You selected an address with a LocatorID of ' + $('#LocatorID').val());
                return false;
            },
            minLength: 3
        });
```

[image]

I immediately thought there must be something wrong with the autocomplete code but after further investigation it appears the function is indeed correctly showing the value field (I tried setting it explicitly) so somehow the 'value' field is picking up the same data as the 'label' field during the binding.

So I next checked the web service but that seems fine. When I query the web service directly I see it is returning the correct data.

```
"SuggestedAddressesSimple": [
      {
        "DisplayAddress": "Mendip Road, Farnborough, Hampshire, GU14 9HL",
        "LocatorID": "630593"
      },
      {
        "DisplayAddress": "Menin Way, Farnham, Surrey, GU9 8DY",
        "LocatorID": "630679"
      }
etc...
```

So is this some kind of data binding issue? How can the returned data not be reflected correctly in the jQuery values?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a simple typo. I had entered "LocatorId" rather than "LocatorID".

What is bizarre is that I was led down the wrong 'discovery' path by the behaviour of jQuery Autocomplete.

I guess the jQuery Autocomplete function is smart enough to realise there is no value passed and to therefore use the label as the value instead.